# How to write test with httprouter

Tags: go

I am writing tests for a simple REST service in GoLang. But, because I am using [julienschmidt/httprouter](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) as the routing library. I am struggling on how to write test.

main.go

```
package main

func main() {
   router := httprouter.New()
   bookController := controllers.NewBookController()
   router.GET("/book/:id", bookController.GetBook)
   http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)
}
```

controllers

```
package controllers

type BookController struct {}

func NewBookController *BookController {
   return &BookController()
}

func (bc BookController) GetBook(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
   fmt.Fprintf(w,"%s", p)
}
```

My question is: How can test this while GetBook is neither HttpHandler nor HttpHandle

If I use a traditional handler, the test will be easy like this

```
func TestGetBook(t *testing.T) {
  req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/book/sampleid", nil)
  rr := httptest.NewRecorder()
  handler := controllers.NewBookController().GetBook
  handler.ServeHTTP(rr,req)
  if status := rr.code; status != http.StatusOK {
    t.Errorf("Wrong status")
  }
}
```

The problem is, httprouter is not handler, or handlefunc. So I am stuck now

Comment: Great... I thought so, but always best to double-check :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just spin up a new router for each test and then register the handler under test, then pass the test request to the router, not the handler, so that the router can parse the path parameters and pass them to the handler.

```
func TestGetBook(t *testing.T) {
    handler := controllers.NewBookController()
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/book/:id", handler.GetBook)

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/book/sampleid", nil)
    rr := httptest.NewRecorder()

    router.ServeHTTP(rr, req)
    if status := rr.Code; status != http.StatusOK {
        t.Errorf("Wrong status")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for me. But do you think if there is another way to make the test code easier to write? Maybe make changes package main?

Comment: Depends on what you think is hard-to-write in this test... If you have many such `TestXxx` functions for testing different handlers and you feel like you're repeating yourself a lot you can extract repetetive code into a function and use it in your tests. E.g. you could have one function, let's call it `testrouter`, that creates a new router, registers every handler and then returns the router, and you can pass the `rr` and `req` straight to its result like so `testrouter().ServeHTTP(rr, req)`...

Comment: And if you want to test a single handler with many different requests have a look at [table driven tests](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/TableDrivenTests).

Comment: Table Driven tests is exactly what i am looking for. Thanks

Comment: Small update: `rr.code` --> `rr.Code` (see [httptest.ResponseRecorder docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#ResponseRecorder)).

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your handler so that it can be accessed as an `http.HandlerFunc`:

```
func TestGetBook(t *testing.T) {
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/book/sampleid", nil)
    rr := httptest.NewRecorder()
    handler := http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        controllers.NewBookController().GetBook(w, r, httprouter.Params{})
    })
    handler.ServeHTTP(rr,req)
    if status := rr.code; status != http.StatusOK {
        t.Errorf("Wrong status")
    }
}
```

If your handler requires parameters, you'll either have to parse them manually from the request, or just supply them as the third argument.

Answer (score 1):

u can try this without `ServeHTTP`

```
func TestGetBook(t *testing.T) {
    req := httptest.NewRequest("GET", "http://example.com/foo", nil)
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()

    controllers.NewBookController().GetBook(w, req, []httprouter.Param{{Key: "id", Value: "101"}})

    resp := w.Result()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    t.Log(resp.StatusCode)
    t.Log(resp.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
    t.Log(string(body))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

here is one more good blog and corresponding working code for this:

> https://medium.com/@gauravsingharoy/build-your-first-api-server-with-httprouter-in-golang-732b7b01f6ab
>
> https://github.com/gsingharoy/httprouter-tutorial/blob/master/part4/handlers_test.go