# How do I test while using httprouter without using controllers?

Tags: go, microservices

I'm trying to write tests for a microservice I wrote using httprouter. I've previously tried to use the answers given here: [How to write test with httprouter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43502432/how-to-write-test-with-httprouter) but that doesn't seem too relevant since I don't use controllers in my microservice. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I have so far:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

func TestCreateURL(t *testing.T) {
  expected := `{"original_url":"https://www.google.com", "short_url":"https://morning-retreat-24523.herokuapp.com/get/3578"}`
  handler := createURL
  router := httprouter.New()
  router.GET("/new/*url", handler)

  req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "/new/https://www.google.com", nil)
  if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
  }
  rr := httptest.NewRecorder()

  router.ServeHTTP(rr, req)
  if rr.Body.String() != expected {
      t.Errorf("Handler returned unexpected body: Got %v but want %v",
        rr.Body.String(), expected)
  }
```

}

createURL is a function like this (but with a lot more in it obviously):

```
func createURL(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {

}
```

Comment: Andy, what does "I am not using controllers" mean, in your case? How is behaviour exposed to your caller?

Comment: "Controllers" is just a state of mind. That answer is still entirely relevant to you. You just don't have a package called "controllers" everything else is still relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write test with httprouter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43502432/how-to-write-test-with-httprouter)

Comment: @AlessandroSantini Well, each separate endpoint has a separate function associated with it. I have no idea what controllers are, whereas the other question has something called controllers (so I thought I'd make that difference clear, in case that's the reason why using the answers from that question hasn't worked for me).

Comment: @Flimzy I've tried to implement your answer from the other question, but that doesn't seem to work. It doesn't seem like the http.Params are being passed to the function in question (i.e. createURL). Here's the bit that I've changed from your original answer: `handler := http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  createURL(w, r, httprouter.Params{})
 })`

Comment: @Flimzy I've changed the question to the answer that was given in the other question, but I am getting a `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` error.

Comment: @mkopriva Perhaps you could help me? You seemed to answer the other question.